# Oracle SQL : Pivot a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have table structure like below :

```
product          supplier            price            qty
-------          --------            -----            ---
SOAP             ABC                 50               10
SOAP             DCE                 50               10
BRUSH            FGH                 30               5
```

I would like to transform this table into :

```
product          supplier_1        supplier_2         price            qty
-------          --------          ----------         -----            ---
SOAP             ABC                 DCE              50               10
BRUSH            FGH                                  30               5
```

how can I do it in SQL? thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you want shown if the 2nd supplier had a different price for soap?

Comment: it will be average for price then sum for qty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
select product,
       max(case when rn = 1 then supplier end) as supplier_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then supplier end) as supplier_2,
       -- ...
       -- max(case when rn = n then supplier end) as supplier_n,
       avg(price) as price,
       sum(qty) as sum
  from(select t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by product order by supplier) rn
         from your_table t
      )
 group
    by product;
```

Comment: if you have a maximum number of suppliers per product, you need to add a corresponding number of columns supplier_1 .. supplier_n. There is no dynamic way with static sql (maybe with dynamic sql and plsql).

Answer (score 0):

```
select product,supplier_1,supplier_2,price,qty from table 
model
return all rows
dimension by(product)
measures(supplier,
  lpad(' ',10) supplier_1,
  lpad(' ',10) supplier_2
)
rules upsert(
  supplier_1[0] = supplier['SOAP'],
  supplier_2[0] = supplier['BRUSH']
)
```

10G or 10G above available.

Comment: pivot clause supported in 11G， please note.

Comment: So sad, we are still in 10G :(

Comment: You can use it fix your problem, I said you could choose another clause "pivot" if you are in 11G